# How to invisible cell tooltip in agGrid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to invisible tooltip on cell hover, how can i do this? is there any value to set on agGrid option?

Comment: What do you mean by "invisible"? Do you want to have a tooltip be displayed on hover?

Comment: actually i want to not show 'tooltip' in cells of one column.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience with ag-grid, tooltip is not automatically set. In your gridOptions or columnDef you should have something like that:

```
    {
      headerName: 'Column With TOOLTIP',
      field: 'firstColumn',
      tooltipField: 'firstColumn',
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'}
    }, {
      headerName: 'Column Without TOOLTIP',
      field: 'secondColumn',
      tooltipField: 'secondColumn',
      filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'}
    },
```

remove the property `tooltipField` to hide the tooltip.